# How to get a RabbitMQ message when a task completes?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using RabbitMQ (and Celery) on Java, here is my code to get a message from RabbitMQ based on a [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) I am reading:

```
QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
while (true) {
  QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
  String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
  System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
}
```

But I only get a message when the task begins - when I would like to get a message when the task is complete. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using QueueingConsumer since it's considered deprecated as explained here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html

On the contrary, you should be creating your own consumer that implements the interface `Consumer` from RabbitMQ libraries. There is a method you will have to implement called `handleDelivery` that will be called every time you get a message. Then, to start it you need to call `channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer)`.

Example:

```
channel.basicConsume(queueName, autoAck, "myConsumerTag", new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                            Envelope envelope,
                            AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                            byte[] body) throws IOException
    {
         //your code here
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still can't get a message when the task completes

Comment: What task are you talking about exactly? This code just receives messages from a queue in RabbitMQ. Inside the `handleDelivery` method you can call whatever you need.

Comment: I use Celery to launch a task, it adds an element on the queue, and I would like to know when the task completes, that means when the element is no more on the queue